# When should I initialise the local variables?

Tags: tensorflow

I am a bit confused by `tf.local_variables_initializer`. I am not sure when to call it.

I see in other peoples code where they just slather on calls like

```
init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
                   tf.local_variables_initializer())
```

Should `init_op` just be called in every TF program? Is this "lazy" TF style of programming?

As an example, consider queues like `input_string_producer` specified as :

```
tf.input_string_producer(file_list, num_epochs=None)
```

does not require `tf.local_variables_initializer()`

However, when specifying actual number of epochs

```
tf.input_string_producer(file_list,num_epochs=1)
```

*does* in fact require that `tf.local_variables_initializer()` is executed.

How does the programmer know when (or when not) to initialise such "hidden" local variables? Shouldn't the `FIFOQueue` init its own variables or have something like queue.initializer?

Answer (score 1):

For local tensorflow jobs, you need to initialize both local and global. For distributed TensorFlow jobs, the chief worker initializes local+global, whereas remaining workers initialize only local.

Comment: So what's the best practice here?  For local usage, just call `init_op` and forget about it?  How to know about "hidden" local vars?

Comment: yes, the best practice is to use `init_op` like in the code you posted